# How can I trim space in XSLT without replacing repating whitespaces by single ones?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The function `normalize-space` replaces sequences of whitespaces by a single space and trims the provided string. How can I only trim the string without the replacement of whitespaces? There are proprietary solutions like `orcl:left-trim`, but I am looking for a non-proprietary one.

**Example:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="trim(/Car/Description)"/>
```

should turn

```
<car>
  <description>  To get more information look at:     www.example.com </description>
</car>
```

into

```
"To get more information look at:     www.example.com"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A solution using just xslt 1.0 templates:

```
<xsl:variable name="whitespace" select="'&#09;&#10;&#13; '" />

<!-- Strips trailing whitespace characters from 'string' -->
<xsl:template name="string-rtrim">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:param name="trim" select="$whitespace" />

    <xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length($string)" />

    <xsl:if test="$length &gt; 0">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($trim, substring($string, $length, 1))">
                <xsl:call-template name="string-rtrim">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring($string, 1, $length - 1)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="trim"   select="$trim" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Strips leading whitespace characters from 'string' -->
<xsl:template name="string-ltrim">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:param name="trim" select="$whitespace" />

    <xsl:if test="string-length($string) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($trim, substring($string, 1, 1))">
                <xsl:call-template name="string-ltrim">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring($string, 2)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="trim"   select="$trim" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Strips leading and trailing whitespace characters from 'string' -->
<xsl:template name="string-trim">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:param name="trim" select="$whitespace" />
    <xsl:call-template name="string-rtrim">
        <xsl:with-param name="string">
            <xsl:call-template name="string-ltrim">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string" />
                <xsl:with-param name="trim"   select="$trim" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="trim"   select="$trim" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Test code:

```
<ltrim>
    <xsl:call-template name="string-ltrim">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="'   &#10;   test  '" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</ltrim>
<rtrim>
    <xsl:call-template name="string-rtrim">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="'    &#10;    test  &#10;  '" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</rtrim>
<trim>
    <xsl:call-template name="string-trim">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="'    &#10;    test  &#10;  '" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</trim>
```

Output:

```
<test>
    <ltrim>test  </ltrim>
    <rtrim>   
    test</rtrim>
    <trim>test</trim>
</test>
```

Comment: I like the clean solution of not having to add additional libraries - thank you for this one! Since I would have to ask the project manager first, whether we can add additional libraries, this solution is clearly preferable for me. I guess there is no way to simply put a parameter at the beginning of the xsl-file to have all fields beeing trimmed, is there? I found `<xsl:strip-space>`, but this is only applied _after_ the other transformations like `concat(...)`, leading to results like `Lastname , Firstname` instead of `Lastname, Firstname`. It looks like there is no such simple solution ...

Comment: @MathiasBader: `xsl:strip-space` operates on the source document, before any transformations, and removes text nodes which only contain whitespace. It probably won't solve your problem. The easiest solution would probably to create a separate transformation that only trims whitespace of selected elements, and use its result as input for the second transformation. This can be done in a single stylesheet using extension functions for a specific processor, or using an external tool/api to invoke the transformations.

Comment: Using a separate (pre-)transformation by an external tool was something that I also had in mind. I just thought that the problem seems to be that common, that I thought there must be an easier solution provided by XSLT that I just didn't find yet.

Answer (score 5):

normalize-space(actualSting) - This will do it.

Comment: This would also remove repeating whitespaces in the middle. I was looking for a solution that doesn't do that.

Answer (score 4):

**Using [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net) (open source library for XSLT functional programming, written entirely in XSLT) one simply writes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:import href="trim.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*/description">
    '<xsl:call-template name="trim">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>'
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<car>
  <description>  To get more information look at:     www.example.com </description>
</car>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
'To get more information look at:     www.example.com'
```

---

**How does the [`trim`](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-trim.xsl?revision=1.1&view=markup&sortby=file) template work**?

It trims the left leading whitespace, then it reverses the resulting string and trims its leading whitespace, then it finally reverses the resulting string.

---

**II. XPath 2.0 solution**:

**Use**:

```
replace(replace(/*/description, '^\s*(.+?)\s*$', '$1'), '^ .*$', '')
```

**Here is an XSLT - 2.0 - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     "<xsl:sequence 
      select="replace(replace(/*/description, '^\s*(.+?)\s*$', '$1'), '^ .*$', '')"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
 "To get more information look at:     www.example.com"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that sounds like a good solution. Am I right that there is no 'native' solution which wouldn't require an additional library (which, of course, would be preferable to import an additional library)?

Comment: @MathiasBader, First of all, using FXSL *is* a native solution -- FXSL is a set of XSLT templates. In case you don't want to use FXSL, one can write a recursive XSLT solution -- it just is not wise to do so when one can just call the already existing (and tested) FXSL solution. If you don't want to save a few hours, or one day of additional work, and to be sure there are no bugs in the solution, then write a transformation from scratch. The purpose of FXSL is exactly to minimize the effort of writing solutions to the problems that are very difficult or "almost impossible".

Comment: @MathiasBader, To put it in other words, with this answer I want: 1. To save you a lot of time and development/verification effort. 2. To let you know that a tool exists that can dramatically decrease your XSLT development time for most tasks and make tasks that are prohibitively difficult ("almost impossible") quite natural and straightforward with XSLT.

Comment: The trim regex doesn't seem to work on a whitespace only string - the assumption being that `''` is the result of trimming a whitespace only string .  This alternative seems to work for me `replace(replace($pStr, '^\s\s*', ''), '\s\s*$', '')`

Comment: @dave, Good catch -- thanks!  I edited the answer with a RegEx that produces the correct result both in the "regular" case and in the case of a white-space-only string.

Answer (score 4):

A very short solution with XSLT1:

```
<xsl:template name="trim">
            <xsl:param name="str"/>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($str) &gt; 0 and substring($str, 1, 1) = ' '">
                    <xsl:call-template name="trim"><xsl:with-param name="str"><xsl:value-of select="substring($str, 2)"/></xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($str) &gt; 0 and substring($str, string-length($str)) = ' '">
                    <xsl:call-template name="trim"><xsl:with-param name="str"><xsl:value-of select="substring($str, 1, string-length($str)-1)"/></xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$str"/></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have any spaces in the middle, you can simply use:

```xsl
translate(/Car/Description,' ','')
```

Comment: Nice idea, but as you might have guessed already, that is unfortunately too much of a simplification.