# add commas with xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

This is my XML structure:

```
<bibliography>
    <element>
        <name>name</name>
        <author><bold>author</bold></author>
        <title>some <italic>title</italic></title>
        <pages>123</pages>
    </element>
    ...
</bibliography>
```

So I add commas with this template:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
  <xsl:if test="position()>2">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

This works, BUT this ignores every element below `/*/*/*`. Because of this every `<bold>` and `<italic>` tag will be ignored. 
How can I fix this?

This is how I handle the `<bold>` and `<italic>` tags from my XML:

```
<xsl:template match="bold">
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="italic">
    <span style="font-style:italic;">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is my full [XML](http://pastebin.com/TWLZ79Gh) and [XSLT](http://pastebin.com/4bVqYWX1), they might help findind the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE (Finally solved it :) )**

---

Basically Following changes from the original xsl :

```
<xsl:template match="bibliography/*/*" priority="0">
        <xsl:if test="position()>2">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Added :

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space()'/>
    </xsl:template>
```

This is the final code :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="bibliography">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Bibliographie</title>
                <style type="text/css">
               .entry  {
                   font-family: Georgia;
               }
           </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="bibliography/*">
        <tr>

                <td align="left">[<xsl:number count="*"/>]</td>
                <td align="left">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>

                </td>

        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bibliography/*/*" priority="0">
        <xsl:if test="position()>2">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bold">
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="italic">
        <span style="font-style:italic;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space()'/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name" priority="1"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And Output :

[image: Latest Output]

---

**Previous Suggestions :**

```
strip-space
```

Use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />`, it will remove 1st ',' problem.

For trimming spaces refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13974534/3603806

You can also use : fn:normalize-space() for trim. Here's the link : http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string

And explanation :

```
fn:normalize-space(string)

fn:normalize-space()
```

Removes leading and trailing spaces from the specified string, and replaces all internal sequences of white space with one and returns the result. If there is no string argument it does the same on the current node

```
Example: normalize-space(' The   XML ')

Result: 'The XML'
```

Change your code to :

```
 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
  <xsl:if test="position()>2">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

This is the result :

[image: This is the result]

Comment: Thanks, but this results in this: `[1] B. Abadie ,On the K-theory of non-commutative Heisenberg manifolds ,` but I want it the other way around: `[1] B. Abadie, On the K-theory of non-commutative Heisenberg manifolds, `.

Comment: Add a space after comma in `<xsl:if test="position()>2">, </xsl:if>`

Comment: This XSLT works but the `<bold>` and `<italic>` tags won't work now. How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes they worked. As you can see [here](http://s1.directupload.net/images/140711/58phxy67.png) bold and italic text.

Comment: I updated my question and added the parts where I handle the `<bold>` and `<italic>` tags. I also updated the linked XSLT file. Maybe this helps you finding the problem. I have no idea why its ignoring these tags. Thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 1):

Your basic mistake is that you are using `xsl:value-of` instead of `xsl:apply-templates`. It's also not clear to me why you're using an awkward and inefficient construct like:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
```

instead of using explicit element names, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

then use specific templates to handle each descendant node - **including** `bold` and `italic`, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="author">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bold">
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="italic">
    <span style="font-style:italic;">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Edit:

If you want to have a generic template for all children of element except author, you could use something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="author" priority="1">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bold">
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="italic">
    <span style="font-style:italic;">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @rei0d You can use one template to match multiple elements: `<xsl:template match="book | article | inbook">`

Comment: Ok, I'll try when I'm back home. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Doing it as you said results in [this](http://s14.directupload.net/images/140711/ywwrcoxe.png) As you can see, there is still space between every element and the comma (first red line) but it seems to be correct for bold elements. Also there is no comma between italic elements and following bold elements (second red line). Have I done something wrong? Here is my [XSLT](http://pastebin.com/4q4zb5yf) after these edits.