# XPath normalize-space, do not replace multiple inner whitespaces

Tags: xpath, trim

How do I translate the text:

```
"  Some   Text in
     my

        "
```

to

```
"Some   Text in
     my"
```

using XPath?

I.e. only trim leading and trailing whitespace (in contrast to `normalize-space`, which also trims intermediary whitespace).

Comment: What version of XPath?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I trim space in XSLT without replacing repating whitespaces by single ones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974247/how-can-i-trim-space-in-xslt-without-replacing-repating-whitespaces-by-single-on)

Comment: I'm using current browsers, so XPath 2.0, I guess.

Comment: If you are using current browsers, then definitely XPath 1.0.

Comment: @MathiasMüller: XPath not XSLT. Okay, then unfortuantely only XPath 1.0.

Comment: I know, there are XPath solutions there. For instance: `replace(/*/description, '^\s*(.+?)\s*$', '$1')`. **EDIT**: But this is XPath 2.0 only, so you are right, this is not a helpful duplicate.

Comment: So there is no way to do that using XPath 1.0? That's most unfortunate...

Comment: No, but if you reveal a bit more of your problem (the purpose of the trimming, the nature of input data, the language XPath is embedded into) - then we might still be able to help.

Comment: Context: I want to match DOM elements using XPath (using Selenium).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65079/discussion-between-mathias-muller-and-d-r).